# rails routing - action not found in nested namespace - get as

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces

The following request should call the show action of the tag controller. But I get

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v0/tags/seeded

The action 'seeded' could not be found for Api::V0::TagsController
```

in routes.rb

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v0 do
      get "/users/:username" => 'users#show', :as => 'user'
      get '/tags/:name' => 'tags#show', :as => 'tag'

    end
  end
```

in app/controllers/api/v0/tags_controller.rb

```
class Api::V0::TagsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render :json => Api::V0::Serializers::Tag.new(params[:name])
  end

end
```

Same for the url suffixed with .json

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v0/tags/seeded.json
```

I use Rails 3.0.11

**UPDATE**

```
$ rake routes|grep api
                     api_v0_user GET    /api/v0/users/:username(.:format)                       {:controller=>"api/v0/users", :action=>"show"}
                      api_v0_tag GET    /api/v0/tags/:name(.:format)                            {:controller=>"api/v0/tags", :action=>"show"}
```

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? Your example works like a charm on Rails 3.1.

Comment: Well, works for me on Rails 3.0.11 as well. Can you show output from `rake routes`?

Comment: What else is in your routes file that you're not showing us?